# Using swagger, how can I define a duration parameter?

Tags: json, swagger, duration

In one of the request I use, I want some attribute to be a moment duration.

How can I define that in Swagger descriptor ?

As far as I understand, something like

```
type: string
format: iso8601
```

would be good. But is it the right way yo do ?

**EDIT** Durations will be expressed using [ISO8601 durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). Which means they will be in the form

- `P1D` for a one day duration
- `P1Y2D` for a one year and two days duration

Comment: What are some sample duration values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chose the following solution

```
 warrantyDuration:
   type: string
   format: iso8601
   description: Warranty duration expressed as an iso8601 duration. Typical values are P1Y, P2Y, ...
   example: P1Y
```

I use the `string` type as values are transferred as strings, and the `iso8601` format, which is the parent format for dates and durations.